# Chromium Downloading Filenames with Spaces

Tags: google-chrome, download-manager, chromium

I am downloading files from Chromium 7.0 on Ubuntu 10.10. If the filename contains spaces, then it doesn't open the file correctly. Chromium seems to pass on the filename unescaped, so most applications interpret them as separate files.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's a known issue:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61981&q=spaces%20in%20filename&colspec=ID Stars Pri Area Feature Type Status Summary Modified Owner Mstone OS

It seems like it hasn't been addressed yet.

Good luck!